# Finding determinant of matrix without expanding

Tags: matrices, determinant

show that determinant
$$\left|\matrix{
x^2+L  &  xy   &   xz \\
xy   &    y^2+L &   yz \\
xz   &    yz   &   z^2+L \\
}\right|
=  L^2(x^2+y^2+z^2+L)$$

without expanding by using the appropriate **properties of determinant**.

All i can do is LHS

$$x^2y^2z^2\left|\matrix{
1+L/x^2  & 1  &   1 \\
1   &   1+L/y^2 &   1 \\
1  &    1   &   1+L/z^2 \\
}\right|$$

Comment: What part are you having problems with?

Comment: I have no idea to start.

Comment: All i can do was just extracting x^2 y^2 z^2 from each row and column.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this form of your matrix
$$\pmatrix{L & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & L & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & L\\} + \pmatrix{x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y & 0\\ 0 & 0 & z}\pmatrix{ x & y & z \\ x & y & z \\ x & y & z \\}$$

and consider your right eigenvector $\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}$ with eignevalue $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + L$

I suspect you may not yet be familiar with eigenvalues, so if that is true, maybe this is some good motivation to learn.

Eigenvector review:
A right eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is defined for a matrix
$\mathbf{A}$ as 
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}\lambda$$
Here we see that
$$\pmatrix{x^2 + L & xy & xz \\ xy & y^2 + L & yz \\ xz & yz & z^2 + L}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + L)$$
In this case all other eigenvectors come from the two dimensional subspace defined as the space of vectors orthogonal to the first eigenvector, and they have eignevalue $L$ (this can be seen more easily from the first form I stated for you matrix).

The unit hypercube of hypervolume one with edges defined by those eigenvectors then is transformed by your matrix to have volume $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + L)L^2$ and that is the determinant for your matrix.

Comment: Thank you, but i am stuck with "right eigenvector with eignevalue x^2+y^2+z^2+L"

Comment: How do i relate the eigenvalue into finding determinant?

Comment: I say hypercube, but this case it is just a three dimensional cube.